# How to findout what cause unicorn workers timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, nginx, timeout, unicorn

People keeps claiming that my website always hang out at some pages. I checked the unicorn stderr log, and found many timeout errors like:

```
E, [2013-08-14T09:27:32.236478 #30027] ERROR -- : worker=5 PID:11619 timeout (601s > 600s), killing
E, [2013-08-14T09:27:32.252252 #30027] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid=11619,signaled(SIGKILL=9)> worker=5
I, [2013-08-14T09:27:32.266141 #4720]  INFO -- : worker=5 ready
```

There are many error messages like that.

Then I go to the rails production log, find the exact requests by searching the unicorn error time minus 601s. These timeout request, all choked at the page rendering phase. The sql of these requests are done already. It just never gets an end:

```
Processing by XXXController#index as HTML
  Rendered xxx/index.html.erb within layouts/application (41.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_sidebar.html.erb (200.9ms)
```

No complete. Most of these requests served successfully. I don't know why at random time, it hang out there.

I have no idea what may cause this. Can anybody give me a clue of how to find the real reason that cause the unicorn workers to timeout?

**Update:**

We used NSC to transfer request and response to unicorn. And to try to improve the timeout issue, we added nginx between NSC and unicorn. It turns out the unicorn worker timeout still happens, and each timeout matches a nginx upstream timeout in nginx error log.

Does anyone knows whether there is some kind of bottle neck in TCP connection of unicorn?

Comment: May be your site is too busy, sometimes the page load time is longer than 600 ms? Sql execution is just a part of the whole response. Or can you config the timeout of unicorn to a larger value and try it again?

Comment: @Bigxiang, it is 600s instead of 600ms. We have upload function so we need to config it such a long time in case of slow connection speed.

Comment: I'm sorry very much, I misread it. I read the document of unicorn, but  haven't found anything useful enough. Some people mentioned that they met the problem when net traffic or cpu was high or used low version of gem mysql.

Comment: @Bigxiang, thanks for your information. We use gem mysql2 0.3.7, I will try to find out whether it is related to the version.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Rack::Timeout to time out before unicorn.  Unicorn timeout uses kill -9, and I don't think that gives you any way to do anything.